# duplicate data insert on multi containers that runs the same service

Tags: node.js, database, concurrency, architecture, microservices

I have a problem with service replica that process the same data .

my code get data from a socket and then insert that data to db. the problem is that if I have 2 containers of the same service (and I have more then 2) they both insert the same and I get duplicated data on my db.

Is there a way to tell only one of them to do the insert ?

I'm using docker and kubernetes but I'm still new with them

```js
function dataStream(data) { // get the data from the socket 
     const payload = formatPayload(lines);
     addToDb(payload);  // I want this to happen only from 1 service 
     broadcast(payload)
}
```

Comment: It seems like both processes will always grab the same data unless your data source is a queue of some sort. Is the data supposed to be unique on each call? If so, what mechanism ensures that?

Comment: hi.  its a good thing for me that they both get the same data. i need this functionality because i broadcast to all my clients(end users)that data.  only the db insert need to happen from 1 of them. my data source is a broker program . its just a socket that spits data no special  mechanism

Comment: Will you please post your AddToDb() code?

Comment: it just do this.collection.insert(asset); the problem is not with the function. on 1 container it works good. the problem is on scale i need to set like a master slave container but i don`t know if there is such a thing

Comment: Well, leaving aside a discussion if your architecture matches your problem, and taking up your idea with the master-slave concept - why not start two deployments of the same container - one with one instance of the master (env arg or cli-parameter master to true) and any many slaves as you'd like in a second deployment! Like this kubernetes will make sure that you always have at least one instance of the master container running...

Comment: i will try that. as i said i'm new to kubernetes, i'm rely interested in your opinion  about the architecture , i guess im doing something wrong here. what is the best solution for this kind of problems